# Filesystem events processor stopped working

Tags: python, pycharm

When launching a Python script in Pycharm I get the message: "Filesystem evenst processor has stopped working". There's only one button to click "close the program" and shuts down Pycharm. When minimizing the message box I can continue working. Can someone provide me with a way to fix this problem?

Comment: Include the code that causes this to happen and your PyCharm version: `Help -> About` in PyCharm

Comment: I also have this problem. It has nothing to do with the code. Whenever we open the PyCharm, it will show up.